# tcpdf encode chinese character

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to create a pdf, but it cant show chinese character, instead it just show square box. I used this [example](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_008/) that provided by them and then changed the cache/utf8test.txt to chinese character but it show "square box". How am I solve this?

Comment: use a Unicode supporting font.

Comment: https://alucard-blog.blogspot.in/2013/06/tcpdf-how-to-display-chinese-character.html

Can try this too. it worked for us very well

Answer (score 10):

You need to use unicode supporting font, like you can use **stsongstdlight**  font for chinese. Hope it helps

Comment: Copied from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alchemy-fr/tcpdf/master/fonts/stsongstdlight.php and placed in `fonts` directory. Japanese and Chinese fonts ok. But do not see Korean fonts, not good for Russian, and do not see some Latvian fonts. Idea to unify/change `$cw = array...` in `stsongstdlight.php` May be someone already has a solution and can advise me?

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
$pdf->SetFont('kozminproregular', '', 12);
```

It just helped me. Hope it also helps u.

Comment: Hey, this worked but only chinese/taiwan but not chinese/china.

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](https://github.com/liuning587/TCExam/tree/master/fonts) copy all files to tcpdf/fonts and now I can just use it with
$pdf->SetFont('DroidSansFallback', '', 8, '', false);

Comment: https://github.com/jenskutilek/free-fonts/blob/master/Droid/Droid%20Sans%20Fallback/DroidSansFallback.ttf 
I think there's also DroidSansFallback Full version

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it to work with the Arial Unicode font.

```
$pdf->SetFont('arialuni', '', 12);
```

Only issue is it's $165 http://www.fonts.com/font/ascender/arial-unicode

Comment: This is a great font, but it has two major drawbacks: first is not free, as you stated, and second there are no bold, italic, and other variants available.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to display both Traditional and Simplified Chinese  chars.

```
$pdf->SetFont('msungstdlight','',10);
```