# TCPDF do not display Chinese on Linux client

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I cannot get `TCPDF` display any chinese character no matter what font I am using.

I crawled and searched everywhere I could, including these interesting posts

[tcpdf-utf-8-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333702/tcpdf-utf-8-problem)
[tcpdf-encode-chinese-character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737772/tcpdf-encode-chinese-character)

but still without success.

The sample #7 from `TCPDF` works well with a lot of different characters sets but if I add some Chinese to the text it will display as squares and the strangest thing is if I change the font to `stsongstdlight` as suggested in one message the text won't display at all - but the header will.

The sample #38 from `TCPDF` with Japanese font doesn't work either. 
Thanks for any advice that could let me find new ideas to try.

Comment: Did you try it with Arial Unicode? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379119/how-to-generate-multilangual-content-pdf-in-php/14455940#14455940

Comment: Yes please refer to the last answer of this thread...

Answer (score 5):

I just tested setting the font like

```
$pdf->SetFont('kozminproregular', '', 12);
```

as suggested in [tcpdf encode chinese character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737772/tcpdf-encode-chinese-character) and it seemed to work fine.

Here is the sample from my output:

[image]

Comment: Tks for this test - This is very frustrating for me as I read several comments say they solve their problem that way....Which is not the case for me ! So now I am really stuck and do not know where to search....Would it be possible some files are corrupted in my machine ? I check kozminproregular.php but as it is only 3.5 kB I guess the fonts drawing are not there...

Comment: By the way are you Linux or Windows user ?

Comment: kozmin is a japanese font, you should use stsongstdlight for chinese

Comment: Thanks for this budwiser, great post!! NOTE @CedSha: Font kozminproregular also needs character set to be compatible, like UTF8 or CP950.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is due to evince PDF reader cannot handle the CJK Chinese generated by TCPDF.
after

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-data
```

Everything started to get better !
I use the font *stsongstdlight* which is designed for Chinese unlike the *kozminproregular* which looks like designed for Japanese. However I have still an issue with the spacing of non Chinese character, there is very big spaces after all T,i,u...
To solve this second issue I convert and use the fonts *arialuni.ttf* but this font is not open source nor free. I tried to convert many other unicode fonts which include Chinese without success.

sources :

- [evince – ubuntu PDF reader – can’t display CJK chinese](http://www.wangchaofeng.com/wordpress/?p=32)
- [creating-pdfs-using-tcpdf-that-supports-all-languages-especially-cjk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426983/creating-pdfs-using-tcpdf-that-supports-all-languages-especially-cjk)