# TCPDF : font helvetica not work for japanese language

Tags: tcpdf

I am working on Multilingual pdf generation. I am using `tcpdf` version `5.9.20`, and font `helvetica` and it's working fine for English character, but displaying ???????? for Japanese character.

I also tried `arialunicid0` font as suggested here http://community.impresscms.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?post_id=43480 . However, it is forcing users to download lang-package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try font "cid0jp", it can probably solve your problem.

I succeed in displaying Japanese and Chinese characters by using this font. It can be found in tfpdf's package.

Comment: Thanks Qian..Yes. I have already implemented this solutions but it will force me to download language pack for adobe reader. Do you know any solutions which will not force user to force any language pack.

Comment: Hi Roopendra, I'm in search of a better solution too. Sorry can't offer more help

Comment: @QianJIN : I just answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379119/how-to-generate-multilangual-content-pdf-in-php/14455940#14455940 maybe it helps.

Comment: @devOp Thanks!I'll check your solution out!

Comment: kozgopromedium also works well for Japanese. Additionally, it works with TCPDF

Answer (score 3):

Most fonts will not work for Japanese, since it needs thousands of characters (whereas English is satisfied with a hundred or so). Developing thousands of characters is expensive, thus Japanese fonts are expensive; and storing thousands of characters takes up space, which makes Japanese fonts multimegabyte. Therefore most Japanese still usually don't use custom fonts, and rely on the preinstalled fonts that come with the OS (or in one of OS-supported packages). Being a graphics designer is kind of expensive in Japan. Those that intend their documents for digital distribution (HTML, PDF) simply do not use any custom fonts.

Comment: So is there any way to generate multilingual PDF using TCPDF?

Comment: I haven't tried, but... This might be a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888991/tcpdf-do-not-display-chinese-on-linux-client (also note a comment about the Japanese on the second answer, and links to similar questions). Good luck.

Comment: Here are also some information about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379119/how-to-generate-multilingual-content-pdf-in-php/14455940#14455940