# HTML2PDF support for japanese language(utf8) is not working

Tags: php, mysql, html2pdf

For report generation in PHP I am using HTML2PDF.

It works fine with English language but not giving proper output for Japanese language.

How can I set utg8 character in hHTML2PDF library.

Is there a way to achieve this in HTML2PDF library.
I am gettign output like "???????????????" instead of Japanese text

In /var/www/html/html2pdf/locale folder following files I found
en.csv, fr.cvs, cs.csv, da.csv

Can we get such file for Japanese too.

Below is my code

```
<?php

$content = ob_get_clean();

// convert to PDF
require_once('Classes/library/html2pdf.class.php');
try {
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
//      $html2pdf->pdf->SetProtection(array('print'), 'spipu');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    $filename = $filename .'_'.date('Ymd');
    $html2pdf->Output($filename.'.pdf','D');//,'D'
}
catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: whats your db and table collation?

Comment: I am able to see same report on my web page in japanese , problem comes when I download in pdf format.

Comment: Its just an html page, no databse.

Comment: I had face same issue with tcpdf, you can refer [solution1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037887/tcpdf-font-helvetica-not-work-for-japanese-language) and [solution2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379119/how-to-generate-multilingual-content-pdf-in-php)

Comment: I updated question with .csv  file , please check and in that way we could fine solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use a specify fonts instead of the default, try this

```
<?php
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8');
    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('arialunicid0'); //add this line
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, false);
    $html2pdf->Output('japan.pdf');
?>
```

Reference: http://community.impresscms.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?post_id=43474#forumpost43474

Comment: I added this line but still same issue.

Comment: Please take a look about the file "_tcpdf_5.0.002/fonts/arialunicid0.php" exists or not?? Also, please try using simple HTML without font style (HTML / CSS).

Comment: It works now, All the content are now in Japanese language. But If I pass Japanese text for file name it gives blank name.

Comment: I think you need urlencode('the_japanese_name.pdf') or rawurlencode('the_japanese_name.pdf').

Comment: I used as $html2pdf->Output(urlencode('注意.pdf'),'D'); but it download file as named E6B3A8E6848F.pdf  . it should be 注意.pdf. What I am missing her. I tried with urlencode and rawurlencode but getting same result.

Answer (score 1):

For polish signs helped this line:

```
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('arialunicid0'); //add this line
```

Look it in Word, for me Helvetica showed squares. After font change problem disapered.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with this function:

> $tpl_data = array_map('utf8_decode',$datas);

Answer (score 1):

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', []);
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('cid0jp'); //using this line
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
$html2pdf->pdf->SetTitle('PDFダウンロード');
$html2pdf->output('download.pdf');
```

I'm using this code and it working!

Answer (score 0):

Set encoding to UTF-8

```
 $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I updated code as per you but still I am getting same output. ????? instead of Japanese text.

Comment: @user3165155 run `$content = utf8_encode($your_insert_content)` at the top

Comment: I tried it gives me output ã‚¤ãƒ³ã‚¿ãƒ¼ãƒ•ãƒƒãƒˆä½¿ç”¨çŠ¶æ, this is not Japanese character.

Comment: Have you tried above solutions by yourself? Are those work for you?

Comment: no, i haven't tried, maybe contact the creators of it